# Running a Python script from the command prompt isn't working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, command-line

In my Python course, we've been asked to output the results of our script to a text file before we submit. This is a simple task and is something I've been doing all semester. However, it doesn't seem to be working today.

Normally I would open a command prompt, `CD` to the directory with my script and then enter the following:

```
car_test.py > car_test.txt
```

Now when I do this, it's opening `Visual Studio 2019` (which is what I'm using as my IDE for Python). I've gone back to other scripts that I have done this with previously and the same thing is happening with those. Oddly enough, it creates a text file, but it's blank. Again, this is happening with previously known working scripts as well.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Answer (score -1):

EDITED ANSWER:

It happened to me again today and I figured out what caused it. Instead of having the default program set to Python for .py files, it had somehow changed to Visual Studio 2019. Once I changed it back to Python, it is now working as I had described below and in the OP.

OLD ANSWER:

After posting this question I walked away to take a break. I can't explain why, but it's working now.

C:\Users%USERNAME%\source\repos\car_test\car_test>car_test.py > car_test.txt

Output file car_test.txt is showing the following:
Car is accelerating:
Current speed:  5
Current speed:  10
Current speed:  15
Current speed:  20
Current speed:  25

Car is braking:
Current speed:  20
Current speed:  15
Current speed:  10
Current speed:  5
Current speed:  0